# Convert audio from iOS Broadcast Extension to be used with WebRTC

Tags: audio-streaming, core-audio, webrtc-ios

I have set up an iOS broadcast extension and audio data is coming in through `processSampleBuffer` as a `CMSampleBuffer`.

I am sending this data through a Websocket connection to a Pion WebRTC sink, configured with `MimeType: webrtc.MimeTypeOpus`.

From the looks of it, the audio generated (`RPSampleBufferType.audioApp`) has 2 channels at a 44100 samplerate.

How do I convert the audio data to be suitable for playing through a WebRTC Opus audio stream?

I had some luck converting it to a PCMA audio stream by using a `AudioConverterNew` and

```
AudioStreamBasicDescription(
  mSampleRate: 8000.00,
  mFormatID: kAudioFormatLinearPCM,
  mFormatFlags: 0,
  mBytesPerPacket: 1,
  mFramesPerPacket: 1,
  mBytesPerFrame: 1,
  mChannelsPerFrame: 1,
  mBitsPerChannel: 8,
  mReserved: 0
)
```

but the audio mostly sounds garbled.